# Adding columns of different index

Tags: python, pandas

I know this adds consecutive columns of same index:

`df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B']`

But how to add columns of different index:

Lets say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df
   A   B    
0  9  40  
1  1  70  
2  5  80  
3  8  30  
4  7  50
```

I need to create another column `C` which is the addition of current index row of column `A`(i.e. idx) and previous index row of column `B`(i.e. idx-1), such as:

```
df
   A   B   C  
0  9  40  (9)
1  1  70  (40 + 1)
2  5  80  (70 + 5)
3  8  30  (80 + 8)
4  7  50  (30 + 7)
```

final result should look like this:

```
df
   A   B  C  
0  9  40  9
1  1  70  41
2  5  80  75
3  8  30  88
4  7  50  37
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html).

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'].shift(1).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Amother solution with [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
df['C'] = df['A'].add(df['B'].shift(), fill_value=0)
print (df)
   A   B     C
0  9  40   9.0
1  1  70  41.0
2  5  80  75.0
3  8  30  88.0
4  7  50  37.0
```

**Timings**:

```
In [2]: %timeit df['C'] = df['A'].add(df['B'].shift(), fill_value=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 457 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit df['C1'] = df['A'] + df['B'].shift(1).fillna(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 544 µs per loop
```

If need function, you can add column names (similar use for another solution):

```
def f(a,b,c):
    df[c] = df[a].add(df[b].shift(), fill_value=0)
    return df

print (f('A','B','C'))
  A   B     C
0  9  40   9.0
1  1  70  41.0
2  5  80  75.0
3  8  30  88.0
4  7  50  37.0
```

Comment: Elegant solutions. Thanks. Is there a way to put this in a function, such that there wont be a need to explicitly state the column names?

Comment: I am not sure if understand you correctly, but I try add solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['C'] = df.A + df.B.shift().fillna(0)
```